# User getting multiple mapped drives for no reason

Tags: windows-7, mapped-drive

One of our users is getting a weird issue where multiple mapped drives are being created for the same thing. The H, S and W drives are supposed to be there, the rest are erroneous and are being created by something unknown. Any idea what the cause is? Drives are usually mapped by group policy and we don't use any of the erroneous letters.

[image: Mapped drives created for no reason]

Comment: Any chance of a rogue script calling `net use`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a script might be using the NET USE command without specifying a drive letter, that causes Windows to use the next available drive letter.
If you can find the script that is creating the mapping using NET USE, then you'll need to use the /delete argument when you remove it:

`net use \\192.168.0.1\Retail /delete`

Answer (score 0):

I never really found a definitive answer for this. After removing some Mcaffee virus scan software that wasn't supposed to be on the machine (because AVG was on there anyway) and disconnected the drives (that I'd done before) the drives just stopped appearing. I can only assuming the conflicting AV products was causing the system to believe that the drive was not successfully created by the GPO, so the GPO kept trying new letters even though it was mapped properly the first time.